# Android video WebView FullScreen not working - onShowCustomView() not called

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, fullscreen, webchromeclient

I'm trying to load a video URL in a WebView in android using the example in this project:
https://github.com/hanksudo/android-webview-youtube-fullscreen

Thing is the `onShowCustomView` method is never called. Whenever I click on the `full screen` button of the video I get this error:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.", source: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=dRekGX6dQRY (0)
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?
Why is the browser interpreting it as a JS request and not a user gesture to make the video fullscreen?
Are there any special flags I can set to enable full screen?

Thanks!

Comment: did you get any solution to fix this? am also suddenly get this bug 3 days back

Comment: Not yet, will post an answer once I do

Comment: what you think the problem, is that webview issue?for me the first lauch its working, but after first lauch full screen not working

Comment: For me is not even working for the first lunch, idk what seems to be the problem, maybe the video player. I'll try changing it and see what happens

Comment: i have a small hack change user agent         webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0");
full screen will work but playerview will go as browser

Comment: @SamwinishereHere I ended up using jQuery with `videojs` and ended up changing the video player, and that one works with fullscreen... also thank you for your response!

Comment: can you show a sample

Comment: @SamwinishereHere Same here too, from the second launch full screen will not work. 
It will work again if you delete this file from device storage: "data/app_name/app_webview/variations_seed".


But we could not be sure if this trick will not cause any crash in future versions of Webview.


I am considering deleting the "app_webview" folder at app startup time.

Comment: Did you get any solution.. Plz help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is this high-priority bug in Google Chrome when used as WebView, fixed in Google Chrome 74.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=945287

Answer (score 2):

My problem solved when I updated my android chrome application to v74.0.3729.112.

related announcement: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASsiW.png